# Perforce Streams: Streams work space creation

Tags: perforce-stream

I have one requirement with streams work space creation.
we have two folders under stream one is 'src' which has source code & other is 'test' which has test cases. As we know stream work spaces are automatically generated from stream views. I want to have my work space where source code will go to one '/test_branch/workspace/' and  tests will go to '/test_branch/tests' folders.
consider **'test_branch'** is the root of the stream client.

We can achieve this in classic depot by editing client view to copy it in specific folders where we want. Is there any way to do that with streams? It really helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with everyone using the stream having the same local structure (i.e. the src files exist in a 'workspace' folder) then you can remap in the stream view. There's a field in the stream spec called "Remapped". If you look at the stream spec from commandline using:

`p4 stream \\streams\maineline` (substituting the stream name for your stream's name)

You'll see a `Paths:` field for sure, and MIGHT see a `Remapped:` field, might not, depending on who's been doing things in there.

If you don't see one, then add `Remapped:` at the end of the file, then under it add:

`src/... workspace/...`

And it will take any files that are in the depot under src/... and locally you'll have them in workspace/...

Last part of the spec should look similar to this:

```
Paths:
    share ...

Remapped:
    src/... workspace/...
```

See https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/p4v/streams.views.html#streams.views.remap

Note that I'm pretty sure the GUI cannot do this. It needs to be done via the commandline.

Edit: Cleaned up directions a bit.

Comment: Hi Gabe, Is that correct syntax ? I am getting error: Error in stream specification.
Imported path 'workspace/...' requires leading slashes in full depot path
Hit return to continue...

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to not have it under the Paths: field. Are you trying to do this in the GUI or on the commanline? The GUI can't do this. You'll have to modify the stream from the commandline. In the form that comes up, if you scroll to the bottom, you'll see a "Paths:" entry with the paths for the stream. It may just be "share ...". After that, at the end of the file, add this:

Comment: Remapped:
    src/... workspace/...

(Needs a newline after the Remapped:)

Comment: I cleaned up the answer/instructions to be a bit more clear. :) Let me know if that works for ya.

Comment: Thanks :) We can also do it in GUI as well. It has remapped field which needs to update ..it really helps. Thanks Again :)

Comment: Gabe, i can copy the folders locally based on my requirement. But for all the users there is one folder with name of there user name in /workspace & /tests I want to place them in there own folder. For one user we can create streams by remapping  "//Test_Stream/main/src/...workspace/<user_name>..." which will copy 'src' folder contents in workspace/<user_name>.. But, for all the users how can we achieve that ? We don't want to create separate stream for every user..

Comment: You can't at the stream level. It depends on what the use-case is. Is the idea that everyone has their own branch of the workspace/... folder that they work in? If that's the case, then you really do want your own stream per user. It's not bad to do that, the system can handle 10s of thousands of streams okay. And in that case, DON'T create folders for their work, just have it be a proper branch. They're lazy branches, so have dbase records are only created for changed files. There will be an integ record, but it's relatively cheap compared to trying to do some magic around user folders.

Comment: Now, having said that, if you really do want individual user folders, then just create them in the main stream, and just have users (by policy, rather than by SCM) work in their own folders. They can just sync their own working folder rather than the whole stream.

Comment: What you lose in that case, is easily using the stream to manage merging/integrating. There will be inter-stream merging that will need to happen for the individual users, which isn't ideal. If the only concern is creating lots of streams, I wouldn't worry about that. It's not a big deal for the system to handle a ton of streams.

Comment: No, We don't want multiple streams to be created. Use cases is like we want to place source code in 'workspace' folder and 'test cases' which has tons of data in 'tests' folder..because we have allocated more space for 'test' folder for every user. So we want to have all users workspace should contain  /workspace/<user_name>/source code and test cases in /tests/<user_name> ..here user_name will change according to user. In classic depot we can achieve this  by simply editing views. Which is not possible with streams :(

Comment: This is likely a longer conversation than can be easily solved on Stack Overflow. :D You should reach out to Perforce support and walk through WHY you want each user to individually have test folders. Is the test code shared across multiple users? But each needs to have their own copy? There's things you can do with import+ paths, but would still require stream creation to support it. Without digging into how the whole system is structured, it's hard for me to advise. Definitely a case for Perforce support.